# limiting distribution of first order statistics

Tags: probability-distributions, order-statistics

> Let $YI$ denote the first order statistic of a random sample of size $n$ from
>   a distribution that has the p.d.f. $$f(x) = \begin{cases}e^{-(x - \theta)}&\theta < x < \infty\\
> 0&\text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$ 
>   Let $Z_n = n (YI - \theta)$. Investigate the limiting distribution of $Z_n$.

I'm pretty much a new learner on this subject and can't find any source reliable to answer this kind (first order statistic) problem. I only found $n$ or last order statistic and didn't know what is the differences.

Do i need to get the  c.d.f first then limit it to the infinity and then use that to find the p.d.f of Zn then turn it into c.d.f again then limit it to infinity?

Comment: Could you edit your own thoughts into the question and then ask us about where you are having difficulties?

Comment: Where did you get this from? If it's from a textbook, then there must be corresponding sections in the text giving examples.

Comment: Just find cdf of $Z_n$ from which the answer would be obvious.